# How to change fragment's status bar color?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

I have activity where I use five fragments on users touch events. I want to set status bar colours for 3 fragments and no statusbar for other two fragments.

If I use below code in one fragment's onCreateView method it changes activity's status bar and I get white color for all the fragments as I have used getActivity() method. So I am searching for solution for fragments.

```
getActivity().getWindow.setStatusBatColor(Color.White);
```

I also tried setting my theme in style.xml and applying to fragemnts root layout in xml but its not working also.

styles.xml

```
<style name="StatusBarColor" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#F5F5F5
    </item>
</style>
```

fragment1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/StatusBarColor"
android:background="@color/home_bg_white"
tools:context="mycontext">
```

thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to change the status bar color programmatically (and provided the device has Android 5.0) then you can use `Window.setStatusBarColor()`. It shouldn't make a difference whether the activity is derived from `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`.

Just try doing:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Just tested this with ActionBarActivity and it works alright.

Note: Setting the `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` flag programmatically is not necessary if your values-v21 styles file has it set already, via:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

---

Edit 2:-

Create a method in your activity

```
public void updateStatusBarColor(String color){// Color must be in hexadecimal fromat
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
}
```

Call this method from your fragment

```
((ActivityName)getActivity()).updateStatusBarColor("#000000")
```

Comment: I want to change fragments status bar so in fragment class it doesnt let me add getWindow method, that is the problem..

Comment: Your fragment is must be a part of an activity. You can write this code in a method of activity and then call it from your fragment. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Tell me one thing, You are showing single fragment at a time or multiple fraqgment

Comment: no single fragemnt.. then as per user slides screen it goes to different fragments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111899/discussion-between-himanshu-shekher-jha-and-aalap-patel).

Comment: @HimanshuShekherJha I changed my app status bar color to White color using your posted answer, I cannot see any status bar items because both status bar items and background color are white. How can I change status bar item color to dark color programmatically?

Comment: just add.. 
Activity activity; // declear
activity =this;  // assign
Window window = activity.getWindow(); 
@AalapPatel

Answer (score 9):

This is the simplest thing you can do :

`getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.white));`

Answer (score 3):

KOTLIN SOLUTION:

When you create an activity and corresponding fragments (1 activity to multi fragments scheme) then you first set a theme in the manifest(can be automatically) and that theme with all their properties are applied to all activity's fragments unless you override the specific property in the desired fragment.
In your case, that property is status bar colour.

To change your status bar colour you need in your fragments onCreate method put next code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        requireActivity().window.statusBarColor = Color.GREEN
 
    }
```

But if you in your theme's style put for example

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Your themes xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_2091765</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    
    <item name="android:statusBarColor"tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> //HERE
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>


</style>
```

then your status bar colour will not be changed because you first need to clear flags or in short you need to override windowTranslucentStatus by doing this:

```
requireActivity().window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```

So final code in the situation where you have defined windowTranslucentStatus = true is next:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                 
                requireActivity().window.clearFlags
                   (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
                requireActivity().window.statusBarColor = Color.GREEN
         
            }
```

Now if you want to do the same for the bottom navigation then the pattern is the same and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just Wright this line in your fragment java class

```
((AppCompatActivity)requiereActivity()).getWindow().setStatusBarColor(R.color.white);
```